# Packaging a Native Library into a Jar

Tags: java, java-native-interface, classpath

I have written a Java Native Interface (JNI) that I would like to package into a JAR and import as a dependency into a Gradle/Java 8 project (Gradle Wrapper 4.6). The only way I am able to use my JNI classes are if I copy the native library to the Main project's /tmp directory before I initialize any module from the JAR that relies on this native library. I am using a class constructor to pass in the tmp file's absolute file path so it can be loaded in the JNI.

My questions are:

- Is copying the native library from the jar and writing it to the Main application's /tmp directory best practice for a production environment? Are there other potential options using a build tool like Gradle?
- Are there any potential known side effects of referencing a native library this way?

Below is how I'm copying the library in the main application:

```
static {
        String libName = System.mapLibraryName("OnnxImp");
        File tmpNativeLib = null;

        try (InputStream stream = System.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + libName)) {
            if (stream == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("failed to find library " + libName);
            }

            tmpNativeLib = File.createTempFile(libName, null);
            try (FileOutputStream tempOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpNativeLib)) {
                IOUtils.copy(stream, tempOutputStream);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            tmpNativeLib = null;
        } finally {
            onnxAPI = new OnnxAPI(tmpNativeLib.getAbsolutePath());
            tmpNativeLib.delete();
        }
    }
```

Below is how I'm loading the native library in the JNI:

```
public class JNIClass {

    public JNIClass() {
        System.loadLibrary("OnnxImp");
    }

    public JNIClass(String tmpNativeLibPath) {
        if (tmpNativeLibPath != null) {
            System.load(tmpNativeLibPath);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No library path passed into JNIClass");
        }
    }

...

}
```

Comment: Copying the library from the .jar to a temporary file is fine.  Deleting it right after copying it is not fine;  no other code will be able to load it if you delete it before they get the chance.  You should [add a shutdown hook](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) that deletes the file.

Comment: It would be better to copy it into the Jar file's own directory if not already present. Then just leave it there.

Comment: Note that if there is any Exception reading the lib stream, you will experience an NPE in the `finally` block.

Comment: @user207421 That assumes that the library is located in a directory that binary code is able to run from.  Even `File.createTempFile()` can have this problem. For example, on a Linux system with `/tmp` mounted `noexec` - a shared object in `/tmp` won't load.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490402/executing-a-bash-script-or-a-c-binary-on-a-file-system-with-noexec-option  That can be a serious obstacle to packaging binaries in jar files.